# How to force @Cacheable work after method execution in spring 3?

Tags: java, spring-cache

I have method that saves entity into database.It is:

```
@Cacheable(value = EMPLOYEE_CACHE,key="#employee.id")
    public Employee createEmployee(Employee employee) {
        try {
            entityManager.persist(employee);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return null;
        }
        return employee;
    }
```

I want the result `Employee` to be cached by key = `id` of `Employee`. Employee's `id` is assigned after `entityManager,persist` method runs.
I know that `@Cacheable` works because of AOP. By default, it stores `employee` into cache before method `createEmployee` runs.

How to force `org.springframework.cache.annotation.@Cacheable` to store into cache after method execution?

The **stacktrace** :

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Null key returned for cache operation (maybe you are using named params on classes without debug info?) CachePutOperation[public com.livelessons.spring.springcore.entities.Employee com.livelessons.spring.springcore.service.EmployeeServiceImpl.createEmployee(com.livelessons.spring.springcore.entities.Employee)] caches=[employees] | key='#employee.id' | condition='' | unless=''
    at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheAspectSupport.inspectCacheUpdates(CacheAspectSupport.java:371)
    at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheAspectSupport.execute(CacheAspectSupport.java:202)
    at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheInterceptor.invoke(CacheInterceptor.java:66)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:204)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy30.createEmployee(Unknown Source)
    at com.livelessons.spring.springcore.EmployeeServiceTest.saveEmployee(EmployeeServiceTest.java:59)
    at com.livelessons.spring.springcore.EmployeeServiceTest.testSpringCacheable(EmployeeServiceTest.java:51)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:74)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:83)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:72)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:231)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:88)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:174)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
```

Answer (score 2):

You may define your own annotation, e.g. @defferedCacheable, and then using aop to store/read the object in cache programmatically.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `@CachePut` instead of `@Cacheable` (with the the same attributes):

> As opposed to {@Cacheable} annotation,
>
> this annotation does not cause the target method to be skipped
>
> rather it always causes the method to be invoked and its result to be placed into the cache.

Comment: I read the same in docs and in my code @CachePut stores entity into cache before method execution. I tried on property which is not null when @CachePut method is called and it stores OK, but if I use null property `id` as `key` of `CachePut` then exception is thrown.

Comment: I even explicitly assined id inside @CachePut method and got the same exception.

Comment: Try calling `entityManager.flush()` just after calling `persist()`. It will assign an id to the employee object.

Comment: Thanks! This doesn't help because @CachePut stores into cache before method call. See my edit for stacktrace.

Answer (score 0):

A little bit late, but maybe will be useful to someone.
@Cacheable define the key from method argument, not the return value, so if you pass new Employee object without id you get null.
Straightforward solution may looks like this:

```
public Employee createEmployeeWithCaching(Employee employee) {
    Employee employee = persistEmployee(employee);
    return saveEmployeeInCache(employee);   
}

private Employee persistEmployee(Employee employee) {
    try {
         return entityManager.persist(employee);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return null;
        }
}

@Cacheable(value = EMPLOYEE_CACHE,key="#employee.id")
private Employee saveEmployeeInCache(Employee employee) {
    return employee;
}
```

But think twice if you really need to return `null` in `catch` block. Obviously it will lead to other exception in `saveEmployeeInCache` method.